# Better way to find all the prime factors of huge integers in C?

Tags: c, primes, prime-factoring, factoring

I have written a code in C that basically makes a list of all the prime factors of a huge number, which is stored using the `gmp` library. Here it is :

```
int is_div(mpz_t number, mpz_t i) {
    return mpz_divisible_p(number,i)!=0;
}

mpz_t * prime_divs(mpz_t number){
    mpz_t * prime_dividers = NULL;
    mpz_t i, i_squared,TWO, comp;
    mpz_inits(i, i_squared, TWO, comp, NULL);
    mpz_set_ui(i,2);
    mpz_mul(i_squared, i ,TWO);
    while(mpz_cmp(i_squared,number)<=0){
        if(is_div(number,i)){
            mpz_fdiv_q(comp, number, i);
            if(is_prime(i)) append(&prime_dividers,i);
            if(is_prime(comp)) append(&prime_dividers,comp);
        }
        mpz_add_ui(i,i,1);
        mpz_mul(i_squared, i ,i);
    }
    mpz_clears(i, i_squared, TWO, comp, NULL);
    return prime_dividers;
}
```

*Note that the function `int is_prime(mpz_t n)` is not defined here because it is quite long. Just know that it is an implementation of a deterministic variant (up to 3,317,044,064,679,887,385,961,981) of Miller-Rabin's primality test. Same goes for the function `void append(mpz_t** arr, mpz_t i)`, it is just a function that appends it to a list.*

So my `prime_divs` function searches for all integers `i`in the range `[2,sqrt(number)]` which divide `number`. If it is the case, it then calculates it's complementary divisor (i.e. `number/i`) and determines if any of them are primes. Would these integers be prime, then they would be appended to a list using `append`.

Is there any way to make`prime_divs` faster?

Comment: Google "Sieve of Eratosthenes"

Comment: The sieve of Erathosthenes is much slower than deterministic Miller-Rabin for huge numbers.

Comment: But testing every number in the range `[2, sqrt(number)]` probably negates whatever efficiency you're gaining by using M-R. You should at least restrict the loop to only odd numbers, since the only even prime is `2`.

Comment: The GMP source tarball includes a program `factorize.c`, in the demos directory, that implements [Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm). This isn't the fastest known algorithm for factoring large integers, but it's a lot easier to understand than the newer ones.

Comment: Ah yes indeed. Can't believe I missed that

Comment: You can instantly double the speed by adding 2 to i each time through the loop (after first checking 2 and 3).  That way you only test odd divisors.  You could use a more complex pattern to weed out even more factors (e.g., only test divisors that are 1 or 5 mod 6, once you're past 3).  The larger the pattern, the further out you have to go before you can apply it.

Comment: Using a length 2 pattern reduces the runtime to 1/2.  Using a length 6 pattern (described above) reduces it to 1/3, so it's still significant.  But the further you go, the less relative benefit there is.

Comment: Actually checking for only the odd integers after 2 doesn't work. If I plug in 348 in my prime_divs function then I miss the prime factor 29. Which should have been captured by `i = 12` even though it is even.

Comment: That's because you only loop `i` up to `sqrt(number)`. Use a recursive solution, where you divide by the factor whenever you find one.

Comment: @Michael Your objection makes no sense.  For 348, it goes like this:  You first find the factor 2, which occurs twice.  So you divide by 4 to get 87.  You then continue looking, and you find 3, which occurs once.  So you divide by 3 to get 29.  You then continue looking up to sqrt(29), but find no other factors.  That means that 29 must be prime, so you're done:  348 = 2*2*3*29.  It is very, very simple.  Did you miss 29 as a factor?  No, of course not.  It's the prime that was left over after checking all possible factors.

Comment: By the way, the technique of checking only odd divisors after 2 is one of the most widely-known optimizations for checking prime numbers.  And it's very obvious.  We used to use it when we were 12 years old and just learning about prime numbers.  If it's not working for you, then you have have a serious bug in your code.  If you think the technique doesn't work, then you really don't understand prime numbers.

Comment: If you really want to quickly factor "huge" numbers, I would suggest looking at different algorithms. For example, what you have presented here will not even come close to competing speed-wise with the quadratic sieve on 50 digit semiprimes. A decent quadratic sieve implementation will factor a 50 digit semiprime in seconds.... the algorithm you have (even if optimized) would take days.

Comment: *...a huge number...* The word "huge" is not meaningful. Instead, specify a reasonable estimate of the maximum size of the number. The length in digits or bits is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you can save time by first checking for small divisors.  Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to set up a list of prime numbers below 5,000 or 10,000.  Then use that list to find the small factors, if any, of your large number.  Every time you find a factor (possibly multiple times for the same factor) divide out that factor to reduce the target number's size.

When you have exhausted the list of small primes, it may be worth running a quick primality check on the large residue before trying to factor it.  This avoids wasting a lot of time looking for factors of a large prime.  You will need to test this idea to see if it actually saves time for you.

Only then should you call the M-R test to find the remaining factors.