# Fast primality testing for large `n` in Python

Tags: python, math, primes

I'm working on a project that requires me to find whether extremely large numbers are prime numbers or not. Of course, I've read how to find prime numbers and have come up with a very simple brute force method:

```py
def is_prime_brute_force(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3:
        return true
    if p == 1 or p % 2 == 0 or any(p % i == 0 for i in range(3, floor_sqrt(p), 2)):
        return false
    return true
```

I've also investigated such probabilistic methods as the [Miller-Rabin Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_and_Solovay%E2%80%93Strassen_primality_test) and Fermat's little theorem (see [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Python) for Rosetta code's implementation of the former).

Though the probabilistic options are an order of magnitude faster than brute force, they're still very slow for very large inputs of `n` (for example, the known prime `10**9999 + 33603`).

I came across an interesting observation (of course I'm not the first to come across such an observation) that **all** primes fit the equation `p = 6 * k + 1` or `p = 6 * k -1`. In Python, such a function looks like this

```py
def is_prime_eq(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3:
        return True
    if p == 0 or p == 1:
        return False

    # The same as `return (p % 6 == 1) or (p % 6 == 5)`
    prime_test = lambda p, a, m : (p % a == m) or (p % a == (a-m))
    return prime_test(p, 6, 1)
```

The above is guaranteed to return true if `p` is a prime, but a true result does not mean the `p` is a prime. An easy example is 25 (25 = 1 (mod 6), but clearly 25 = 5^2).

I'm wondering if there's some more general way to apply this interesting property of primes, perhaps with different values of `a` to improve the speed of my `is_prime` function.

Comment: Just use a probabilistic test. Ideally one someone else already implemented.

Comment: Although all primes (other than 2 or 3) are of the form 6k+1 or 6k-1 for integer k, not all numbers of the form 6k+1 or 6k-1 are prime.

Comment: @enumaris thanks, I forgot to include that detail. I've updated the question.

Comment: You may find the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313968/better-way-to-find-all-the-prime-factors-of-huge-integers-in-c/61321444#61321444) helpful.

Comment: *...probabilistic options are an order of magnitude faster...* Understatement of the century.

Comment: probabilistic algorithms are probabilistic. Only the details of your requirement can tell you if that is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather helpful solution was posted on math.stackexchange ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652895/fast-primality-testing-for-very-large-primes/3652956#3652956)) which I've mirrored below

---

In relation to this algorithm, your proposed "faster" algorithm is equivalent to

```py
def is_prime_brute_force(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3:
        return true
    if p == 1 or p % 2 == 0 or p % 3 == 0:
        return false
    return true
```

Hopefully you see why this is not terribly helpful.  Any composite which is a product of primes `>= 5` will evaluate as a prime.  Usually we use probabilistic primality tests (e.g. Miller-Rabin) for numbers whose prime divisors are all sufficiently large, so ignoring all prime divisors greater than 3 makes it fairly useless.

---

Primality tests are by their nature rather costly on current hardware.  The best you can do is to try to optimize for some given assumptions on the input.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a probabilistic test. Probabilistic tests are the state of the art in primality testing, much faster than any deterministic test, and inventing anything faster would require world-class number theoretical expertise.

gmpy2 is probably your best option in Python. It has [built-in support](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advmpz.html#advanced-number-theory-functions) for multiple probabilistic primality tests and other number theory functions, as well as its own arbitrary-precision int type optimized for much faster operations on large values.